# How to get windows username

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the windows username on an aspx page.

I have tried the following:

```
<% System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()) %>
<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name %>
```

But all that does is give me *IIS APPPOOL/SBalance*  - which is not the windows username!

However if I add the following server control:

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
```

this does successfully pre-populate with my domain and username.

So how can I get the domain/username as a string on the aspx page without using a login control?

Thanks

Comment: IIS APPPOOL/SBalance **is** a windows username... it's automatically created in the same name as the application pool that your app is running in under IIS. I suspect you're looking for the asp.net currently logged in user name, right?

Comment: seems like you may just need to enable windows authentication, this should work too, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

Answer (score 3):

If you use Windows Authentication you can get the username via `User.Identity.Name`

```
string windowsLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: This will only work if you are using Windows Authentication on your website.

Comment: thanks. what namespace is the user in? <%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %> does not work

Answer (score 0):

you will need to enable impersonation in the web.config

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

then you need to enable windows impersonation in IIS and disable anonymous authentication

Comment: if you're going to down vote, it's polite to add a comment as to why. if you want the user's windows accountname you need impersonate.